# Ionic not starting Why?

Tags: ionic-framework

[image: Errors that occurred]

> [ERROR] ng has unexpectedly closed (exit code 1).

I have tried to uninstall the node modules and reinstall them but it didn't work.

Comment: try as follow `npm i mini-css-extract-plugin -D`

Comment: Copy console output and paste as text

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it needs to update `wepback` from ^4.1.0 to ^4.3.0 or later version

or

```
npm i mini-css-extract-plugin -D
```